# Why doesn't this htaccess RewriteRule "stick"?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect http://vacation.website.com/category/spa-vacations/ to http://website.com/vacations/spa-vacations/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ $1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vacation\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://website.com/vacations/$1 [L,R=301]
```

[image: Screencap from htaccess tester]

With this htaccess, the first rule seems to be applied and removes "category" from the URL - then it's like it never happened and I'm left with http://website.com/vacations/category/spa-vacations/

Why doesn't the first change to the URL stick and is it possible to make it do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect

`http://vacation.website.com/category/spa-vacations/`

to

```
http://website.com/vacations/spa-vacations/
```

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?vacation\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ https://website.com/vacations/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test.

Comment: @Mike glad to help , you need just to rewrite part of uri  category/whatever to vacations/whatever but with new host name , so i first catch sub.domain and then catch a uri that start with category/whatever and present whatever by regex to utilize it in target vacations/$1 so , $1 presents (.*) in pattern